# Options and advice for two-point aerial yoga hammock

Tags: ceiling, joists, hanging

I'm looking to hang an aerial yoga hammock in our garage from 2 attachment points. I'm based in Australia which might change some of my measurements/ratings so sorry in advance!

I can use a manhole to access one third of the ceiling. The rest of the ceiling is under our second level, blocked by an i-beam with the brick wall on it (flanges are around 7mm thick).

The part I can access has MGP10 rated joists around 35x90mm in size.

**So my question is:** can eye hooks be used directly in the joists/flange as long as they are correctly rated and supported on top with a washer/plate? Or would spanning a large beam across multiple joists then drilling into that (or another solution) be the preferred method here?

It's not a passive hammock, so due to jumps/drops of a few feet most guides recommend around 800kg+ bearing capacity to avoid surprises.

Hiring a specialist is another option but most guides recommend finding a certified rigger which doesn't seem to be getting many matches around here (maybe we call them something else).

**Edit:**

**Photo inside roof:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtc3h.jpg

**Some rigging ideas:** https://www.aerialyogaonline.com/rigging-residential/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be difficult for us to give you any sort of reliable answer on this. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: How far do your joists span? (Clear dimension from support to support.)

Comment: @LeeSam it's a little inconsistent as it's near a corner and the manhole so they vary in size. I have added an image. The closest (longest) is 190cm between eaves and i-beam however it isn't attached to the i-beam, just resting. The end at the eaves is cut triangular then attached to the upper beams with a connector plate. Space between joists is 56cm.

Comment: No, I would not drill all the way through a ceiling joist. The size of hole needed for your eye bolt will weaken it. How far apart do you need your attachment points to be?

Comment: @Mattman944 yes I figured the joists were too narrow. The distance is not very strict but around 55cm would be ideal.